# in subset sum problem , when i am taking memo[sum][size] i have to add sum<0 but not in case of mem[size][sum] .i do not why . please explain

Tags: c++, dynamic, dynamic-programming

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int issubseset(vector<int> subset,int size,int sum,vector<vector<int>>&memo){
   // if(sum<0)return 0;
    if(sum==0)  return 1;
    if(size<0) return 0;
    
    if(subset[size]>sum) issubseset(subset,size-1,sum,memo);
    if(memo[size][sum]>=0) return memo[size][sum];
    memo[size][sum] = issubseset(subset,size-1,sum-subset[size],memo)||issubseset(subset,size-1,sum,memo);
    return memo[size][sum];
}

int main(){
    vector<int> subset{3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2};
    int sum=9;
    std::cout << subset.size() << std::endl;
    vector<vector<int>> memo(subset.size(),vector<int>(sum+1,INT_MIN));
    printf("%s",issubseset(subset,subset.size()-1,sum,memo)?"true":"false");
}
```

Question:

> Given a set of non-negative integers, and a value sum, determine if there is a subset of the given set with sum equal to given sum.

When I am interchanging the `memo` 2d array from `memo[size][sum]` to `memo[sum][size]`, I have to uncomment the the first line in `issubseset` function . If I am just changing the shape of `memo` it should not have any effect since the array will be filled as per recursion and I am already covering base cases. If `memo[size][sum]` can work without the `if(sum<0)` line, why can't `memo[sum][size]`?

Comment: Using a negative vector index is wrong in both cases and leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: we can access the  vector value since it is initialised already and we  can change also . isnot?

Comment: Please have a read through (How do I ask a good question?)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] and also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's pretty hard to see what's going on in this code, even more so when we can't actually see the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour thanks to `sum` being used as an index even though it is sometimes negative. This is true of the code you posted as well as the equivalent with the shape of `memo` changed.

To find out why this happens, we'll have to look closely at your code. I'll reproduce it here with a couple of helpful labels:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int issubseset(vector<int> subset,int size,int sum,vector<vector<int>>&memo){
    // (1)
    if(sum==0)  return 1;
    if(size<0) return 0;
    
    // (2)
    if(subset[size]>sum) issubseset(subset,size-1,sum,memo);

    // (3)
    if(memo[size][sum]>=0) return memo[size][sum];
    memo[size][sum] = issubseset(subset,size-1,sum-subset[size],memo)||issubseset(subset,size-1,sum,memo);
    return memo[size][sum];
}
```

Now let's walk through the code, assuming `sum` is negative and `size` is non-negative. If we get to (3), we've encountered undefined behaviour.

The checks for base cases at (1) do not trigger in this case, so execution carries on.

Now we're at (2), which is a very important line. It is the last line before the potentially troublesome (3), so there's a lot riding on it. We had better be sure it doesn't let execution go to (3). Unfortunately, even without looking deeply, we can tell that it's not up to the task: there isn't any control flow in this line (aside from the branching for the `if` of course). There's no question about it now: execution will definitely go ahead to (3), resulting in undefined behaviour.

Thankfully the fix is easy. Add a `return` for the recursive call in (2):

```cpp
// (2)
if(subset[size]>sum) return issubseset(subset,size-1,sum,memo);
```

This *will* prevent execution from continuing to (3) whenever `sum` is negative: since `subset[size]` is non-negative and `sum` is negative, `subset[size] > sum` will be true and the return path will be taken. I'll leave it to you to determine whether this is the correct thing to do for your given problem.

The same analysis holds when the shape of `memo` is changed. The fact that you only noticed a problem with one shape and not the other is luck of the draw, really. There is no "why", it just happens to be that way. Either version of the code could *literally have done (or not done) anything else* (we don't call it **undefined** behaviour for nothing). I'll avoid going on a tangent about best practices, but I will give one piece of advice: use `.at()` instead of `[]`, at least until you've proven the code correct (and even then, keeping `.at()` around may not be a bad idea). `.at()` will check each index and will scream at you (throw an exception) if it is invalid. Unlike `[]`, `.at()` will not silently break your code when given a bad index, making much nicer from a debugging standpoint.

Comment: you are gem man. Thanks for such deep analysis . I will definitely use .at afterwards.